# The problem of integer solutions for nonlinear systems of equations

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

We have a system of equations：

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)+abc=0$；

$(a-b)c^5+(b-c)a^5+(c-a)b^5=0 $。

Requirement $a\neq b \neq c \neq0 ，a+b+c\neq 0 $

The question is, if we have $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, prove that b and c are neither integers nor in the form of $\frac{1}{2}(p\pm{\sqrt{q}})$, with p, q$\in\mathbb{Z}$，$q>0$。

Because the equation is a symmetric polynomial about a，b，c。What we want to prove is that the system of equations does not have three integer solutions, nor does it have one integer, and the other two are solutions in the form of $\frac{1}{2}(p\pm{\sqrt{q}})$。